# Как передать id в моем случае?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть список фотографий( юзеров ) в сайдбаре и например я хочу отправить сообщение лично, одному из них
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

id я могу взять с фотки, а вот как ее передать в файл message.php? (На картинке справа) Как мне дать понять, кому я хочу написать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы отправляете сообщение AJAX, можно в момент выбора добавить data-атрибут к input-полю отправки

```
<input type='text' name='message' data-id='3232' />
```

Затем в JavaScript его можно прочитать, например, в библиотеке jQuery для чтения таких атрибутов предусмотрен специальный метод data

```
$('input[name=message]').data('id')
```

Если вы отправляете данные классической кнопкой Submit, то в форму можно добавить скрытое поле

```
<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='3232' />
```

Которое можно заполнять в момент выбора пользователя

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что в момент нажатия "написать сообщение" отправляется в message.php содержание input?

Comment: Нет, не совсем, в момент нажатия "написать сообщение" вы модифицируете DOM-структуру текущей страницы, таким образом, чтобы форма содержала информацию об id пользователя, которому необходимо написать сообщение.

Comment: Так у меня вопрос был такой, как сделать так, чтобы форма в message.php содержала информацию об id, каким способом её получить?

Comment: Добавьте data-id='3232' в каждое изображение, где 3232 - идентификатор пользователя и при клике на изображение извлекайте идентификатор из data-атрибута $(this).data('id').

Comment: К примеру, на картинке есть вариант "зайти в гости" я реализовал так, при нажатии отправляю (id) с помощью  get на profile.php, и там из URL его выбираю.  С message.php так не получиться

Comment: У меня все так и написано) и теперь,  когда у меня есть id, мне надо передать дальше

Comment: Я понял, что вы предлогаете сделать отправку сообщения в том же файле, где я получаю id, а я хочу, написать функцию в другом файле

Comment: Пока не очень понятно, есть возможность передать id этому другому файлу через GET-параметр message.php?id=3232 ?

Comment: Да, но у этого файла message.php нету url, он инклудится в другой файл, тогда не получится принять get, короче мой вывод, что я придумал херню, которую невозможно реализовать, либо никто так не делает)) спасибо за старание!

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан если вы хотите получить id в message.php который инклюдится в другом файле тогда id нужно получать в самом файле который инклюдид message.php. Перед **include** обьявите перменную например `$userId = $_GET['user_id'];`
После `$userId` будет доступен в message.php (осталось лишь проверить или она задана через `isset($userId)` в message.php

Comment: Ваш вариант требует перезагрузку страницы, мне же это не подходит, все через ajax. Я все это запланировал для того, чтобы одну и туже функцию не писать в каждом файле, у меня отправка сообщений возможна с каждой страницы, и не хотелось бы столько повтора.